# Panel data set in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using Tensorflow for DNN regression with a panel data set. The data set is a pool of 12 months of cross sectional data, each month has `n` records and each record has `m` dimensions (i.e., `m` fields). So the dataset theoretically look like `t` x `n` x `m` and from the documentation, I should be using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`. The trouble is, `n` can vary month-by-month (i.e., sometimes there are 700 records that month, sometimes 800). So how would you feed in such a tensor?

Cheers,
Steve

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your dataset, but did you consider declaring n as batch? So order your  dataset as n x t x m and pretend that n is the batch size.

Comment: I suppose I can programmatically, but wouldn't the network be biased towards later records?

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that the estimated model from t-12 to t is used to predict t+1. So the input tensor is `n` x `m`

Comment: Ok, then guess you have two options: 1. Set n to the smallest n in your estimator and cut all other values, wich is not very nice. Or 2. you customize the DNN regression for your purpose. Therefore you need to set the input size variable (set input shapes you don't know as -1).